# How to display data in smarty when using PDO with prepared statement and executing inside foreach?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array( 
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true));

$selectNumberTitle = $dbh->prepare("SELECT AdvertNumber, AdvertTitle FROM `adverts` WHERE AdvertNumber = ? ");

foreach ($advertnumber as $i => $number) {
    $selectNumberTitle->execute(array($number));
    foreach ($selectNumberTitle as $row) {
        echo $row['AdvertNumber'] . ') ' . $row['AdvertTitle'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Above code works nicely. I need the same output in smarty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$selectNumberTitleMerge = array();    
foreach ($advertnumber as $i => $number) {
    $selectNumberTitle->execute(array($number));
    foreach ($selectNumberTitle as $row) {
        $selectNumberTitleMerge[] = $row;
        echo $row['AdvertNumber'] . ') ' . $row['AdvertTitle'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
$smarty->assign('selectNumberTitleMerge', $selectNumberTitleMerge);
```

and code inside my template:

```
{foreach $selectNumberTitleMerge as $r} 
    {$r.AdvertNumber})
    {$r.AdvertTitle}
    <br>
{foreachelse}
    .. no results .. 
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 2):

You save the data you want to display in a variable like an array. After that you [assign this variable to smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl#language.assigned.variables). So, you split this problem into two:

1. Read the data from the database in an array.
2. Display the variable (array) in your smarty template.

Comment: Thank! @Progman "You save the data you want to display in a variable like an array" - This is what I needed to hear.